# How to get the complete EXIF ​information of album photos in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am developing a simple app with swift. I want to get the complete EXIF ​​of this picture after selecting a picture in the system album. At present, I can only get some incomplete ones. How can I solve it? Thanks for the help! The Code is below.

'''

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showImagePicker) {
                ImagePickerView(sourceType: .photoLibrary) { info in
                    print("info = \(info)")
                    
                    if let uiImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage,
                       let url = info[.imageURL] as? URL,
                       let cgImage = uiImage.cgImage,
                       let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url as CFURL, nil),
                       let metadata = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, nil) as? Dictionary<String, Any>{
                        self.model = CGImageModel(cgImage: cgImage, metadata: metadata.description)
                        print("metadata = \(metadata)")
                        //                        print("exif data = \(String(describing: metadata[kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary as String] as? [String : AnyObject])) ")
                    }
                    else{
                        print("metadata is empty")
                    }
                }
            }
```

'''

The print data I got is below

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEWs3.png)

---

But what I want is GPS information

Comment: How do you know you don't get all metadata?

Comment: I'm not sure, but what I want is GPS information

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the PHAsset representing the chosen photo in the library and ask the library for that asset's data.